# Regarding Apostol's Definition of Riemann Integration and Darboux's integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, riemann-integration

In [Apostol calculus Part 1](https://library.iitp.ac.in/images/btech_ebook/Calculus,%20Volume%201%20by%20Apostol%20%5BVol.-1%5D.pdf) page 74 integrabilty of a bounded function on a closed interval [a,b] is defined as follows

Let  $S_f=\{s:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: s\ \text{is a step function and } s\leq f\},\\
        T_f=\{t:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: t\ \text{is a step function and } t\geq f\}.$

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. The lower integral of $f$ is the quantity
$
        \underline{I}(f)
    =\sup\left\{\int_a^bs(x)dx:s\in S_f\right\},$

and the upper integral of $f$ is the quantity
$\overline{I}(f)=\inf
    \left\{\int_a^bt(x)dx:t\in T_f\right\}.$
We say that $f$ is Riemann integrable if $\underline{I}(f)=\overline{I}(f)$, in which case this quantity is called the integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$ and denoted by $\int_a^bf(x)dx$.

I wanted to know as to how this definition of Riemann integrability equivalent to the Darboux Integral definition?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral#Refinement_of_a_partition_and_relation_to_Riemann_integration